# how to get website data with "attribute hidden html5"

Tags: c#, html

I want to read source code from a website, however the Content is hidden ,example :

this code , that read by Firefox
**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stc.m.nixcdn.com/js/html5-player.0.1.js"></script>
    <div class="player">
        <div class="hide-html5">
            <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
                <source src="http://aredir.nixcdn.com/4872ac6dba1848a6300a022df6b76789/5357217a/NhacCuaTui854/LacDuong-PhamTruong-3025698.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
        </div> 
        <div id="play" class="play control">
        </div> 
        <div id="progress">
            <div id="progress_box">
                <div id="load_progress" style="width:0px;">
                    <div class="hand-control" id="hand_progress" style="left:-7px;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="play_progress" style="width:0px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="play_time"> 
            <span id="current_time_display">00:00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        bodyLoaded();
        document.getElementById("audio").addEventListener("ended",
                function() {
                    playAudio();
                }, false);
    </script>
```

**

C# code :

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                data = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

but Source code , that downloaded not have the content.
 I using c#. Thanks.

Comment: try to add user-agent header, some web sites block robot by check it.

Comment: Can you tell me , that how to do it @emn178 . thanks.

Comment: You can use like this: `client.Headers.Add("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53");`

Comment: i'm tried but it not effectively .!@@. Help me !

Comment: what page do you want to get? If the page is render by JavaScript, WebClient can't get the final result. Maybe you can try to use WebBrowser because it can run JavaScript.